# Robotframework does not find ENV-Variable

Tags: shell, robotframework

I have created a docker container with an environment variable like this:

`docker run -d -it --name upload-testservice-1 --env SERVICE_URL=http://localhost:9400 image`

If I run the command `env` in the shell of the container, I receive lots of env-variables, containing the wanted `SERVICE_URL=http://localhost:9400`

When I now want to use this env-variable in my robot test like the [docs](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20Environment%20Variable) tell me:

`${test} =    Get Environment Variable   SERVICE_URL`

or like this:

`${test} =    %{SERVICE_URL}`

I receive the error `Variable '${SERVICE_URL}' not found.`

Can you tell me whats wrong and how I can access the env-variable?

I also tried:
`${test} =    Evaluate    os.environ.get("SERVICE_URL")`
generating the same error.

Comment: Are you running robot inside the container? What command you used to call robot?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be the formatting.

`${test} =    Get Environment Variable   SERVICE_URL` is missing a   character between `Get Environment Variable` and `SERVICE_URL`? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-separated-format recommends using 4 space; however, 2 spaces also should suffice (not 3).

I could not use `Get Environment Variable`; however, I would use [Set Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable).

```
*** Test Cases ***
Logging Env Var To Console
    Log To Console    %{SERVICE_URL}
    ${test}=    Set Variable    %{SERVICE_URL}
    Log To Console    ${test}
```

By implementing your container example such that env vars are passed as container environment variables (not variable parameters of robot cli) I was able to get the following output

```
Logging Env Var To Console                                            http://localhost:9400
..http://localhost:9400
Logging Env Var To Console                                            | PASS |
```